# 'no such file or directory' on a file that isn't accessed

Tags: ruby, powershell

I'm writing a small Ruby script that does a statistical analysis on a list of names generated by [another script of mine](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/newbiedoodle/RandomBits/master/MarkovNameGenerator/name_gen.rb).

When I run it with this command:

```
ruby [first script] [args] | ruby -- [second script] _
```

it throws this error:

```
./name_gen_test.rb:15:in `gets': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - _ (Errno:ENOENT)
        from .name_gen_test.rb:15:in `gets'
        from .name_gen_test.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

*(Apologies for typos; Powershell wouldn't let me copy/paste)*

This is line 15:

```
until (cur_line = gets).nil?
```

Then there's the body of a loop, the rest of the code, etc. However, if I put this line:

```
gets
```

as the *very first line*, I get the same error. In fact, if I totally empty the file and have nothing but a call to `gets`, I get the error that the file '_' cannot be found.

How can I make it understand that '_' is a command line argument and *not* a file to be... read from, I guess? Why doesn't `gets` work like I expect it to (i.e. reading from the standard input)?

I'm running it with Powershell, if that makes a difference.

Sorry if this is a duplicate; simply Googling the error message leads to a dozen different issues and a dozen different solutions, none of which apply, and I couldn't figure out how to put this problem into a Google query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STDIN.gets` will do what you want. By default, [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) is (pretty much) equivalent to `ARGF.gets`. [`ARGF`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/ARGF.html) reads from standard input if there are no `ARGS`, and from files that correspond to `ARGS` if there are.